# Oracle cloud remove instances?

Tags: oracle, cloud

https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/oow19-oracle-free-tier-091619.html
https://console.uk-london-1.oraclecloud.com/a/compute/instances

I registred Oracle cloud instances in September. In December 18, instacnes was removed . Is this the trial period? Why was there no deletion warning? How can I find out the details?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Oracle Cloud T&Cs and not programming. Sorry, but we don't do licensing advice here.

Comment: You might find [this tweet from Franck Pachol](https://twitter.com/FranckPachot/status/1207719347617239041) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with Oracle's Always Free instances. It's the compute nodes so your data should still be safe. Franck Pachot has blogged about the cause, and more importantly how to recover from it, [here](https://medium.com/@FranckPachot/3-months-after-the-oracle-always-free-tier-unexpected-termination-a9a76108cb7).

---

I know link only answers are low-quality answers but I suspect other Seekers may come to SO in search of a solution. I don't want to hijack Franck's work to post here so I'm making this answer CW.